# VBA - Using Autofilter to filter and copy data

Tags: vba, copy, autofilter

I'm new to VBA. At the moment I'm trying to filter data in one sheet and copy the results to another sheet. Actually that works good but it doesn't work for the case when the autofilter delivers any results. In that case, I would see only the header.

I tried to solve it by counting the rows in the visible range. Now I have this problem:

For the Case with 4 results (Header + 4 Rows results) I get with following code 4 rows:

```vb
Sheets("Table1").UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

When I have the case with 1 result (First row header + 1 row result) I get with the same code as result 1. And now my problem: when I have 0 results I also get with the same code 1. So there is no difference between non and one result. And when I try counting without the offset

```vb
Sheets("Table1").UsedRange.Offset(0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count'
```

I always get a 1. Even when they are results. So it seems that without the offset the code is just counting the header.

Can someone help me?

That's the part where I'm using the autofilter:

```vb
File = "File.xls"
Workbooks(File).Sheets("Table1").Activate
    
Sheets("Table1").Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(Datum1), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(Datum2)     

Sheets("Table1").Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*Text*" 'Filterung angepasst

Debug.Print "Result:"
Debug.Print Sheets("Table1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
Debug.Print Sheets("Table1").UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

If Sheets("Table1").UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
    'Code for Copying
End If
```

Comment: You cannot reliably use Rows.Count on a range which may contain multiple areas: you will only get the count of the rows in the first area.  Try something like `Cells.Count/[columnCount]`

Comment: What I do for this is Just `LastRow = Sheets("Table1").Cells(Sheets("Table1").Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` and if `LastRow` is greater than 1, then there are results. That's assuming your headers start in row 1 and you always have data in column A or else, find a column which will always have data.